# Git repository seems empty but it is not

Tags: git, bitbucket

Hello guys I seem to have a problem
My friend created a repository on Bitbucket here:
bitbucket.org/radosav_brajic/chatspammer

And he said he wrote some code
but when I download it I see only two files costributors.txt
and gitignore

Why is that??Could someone help me??

Comment: Your friend may have committed, but didn't push

Comment: He may have "wrote" some code , but did he commit and push it to the branch'(s)?

Comment: He said the code is on git but i dont see it ...Could he somehow locked the repository and that source can be viewed by certein people....Can I give you pass username and pass So that you can check it???

Comment: Git is decentralized... So it can be "in git" on his machine... Or it could be in a separate branch of Bitbucket that you need to checkout

Comment: There is only one branch I dont see what could be the problem I just cloned repository and still only those two files

Comment: @legolas your friend has to set up a `git remote` and then `git push` to that else you won't be able to access any of his work

Comment: and don't give credentials... Make the repo public

Answer (score 1):

1) He committed, but not pushed his changes into bitbucket

2) He created a branch and commited into it (and pushed changes than). By default you are checking out on master branch. If changes are in some other branch, you need to check on it.

- git clone your repo
- `git branch -r` in that repo
- if there some not-master branbches, you should chckout on them and run 'git log'
- you can also try to run 'git log --all' to log all commits from all branches.